# Disable Button Until Fields are Full Pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to keep a button disabled until the form fields are filled in and I cannot seem to accomplish this. I've created a small example with a single field but the principle will be the same with a larger form.

Can anyone help?

Code:

```js
function checkForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var cansubmit = true;

  if (name.value.length == 0) {
    cansubmit = false;
  }

  if (cansubmit == false) {
    document.getElementById("submitbutton").disabled = true;
  }

};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="checkForm()" />

<button type="button" id="myButton">Test me</button>
```

Comment: Why don't you disable it by default and only enable it when you get the desired result on the other inputs?

Comment: You should open your console and look for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your sample:

1. `var name` is assigned to the value string of the name element, then you check the `value` property of that - the string has no `value` property.
2. the `id` of the submit button is `myButton` so use that id to get it by id (when setting the `disabled` attribute).
3. You can disable the submitbutton until the length of the name input is greater than 0.

And disabling the button initially sounds like a good idea, right?

See corrected example below:

```js
function checkForm()
{
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var cansubmit = (name.length > 0);
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = !cansubmit;

};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="checkForm()" />

<button type="button" id="myButton" disabled="disabled">Test me</button>
```

You might also want to consider handling change via methods other than keypress - e.g. mouseup, etc... I tried adding `onchange="checkForm()"` and it works but only on blur (focus-change)...

Comment: I'm having some trouble scaling this up into an array of variables.  The array always seems to be registering the length of what's inside as > 0 because I'm not drilling down far enough to the level of the items in the array and then THEIR variables.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/niyibufebo/3/edit?js,console,output) - refer to the inline comments in the javascript function...